# How to select input option after second ajax complete, JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm loading data from mysql to php with ajax. I want to create edit function for my website. This edit will be on modal.
Select input with options (subcategories) is loading by ajax after radio input categories is loaded with previous ajax.

I've tried several jquery events to change select option, but no one worked.
This is script code in my modal file.

```
<script>    
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $("#editexp'.$poz.'").on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
            $("input[name=payment'.$poz.'][value='.$method.']").prop("checked", true);

            $("input[name=kategoria'.$poz.'][value='.$catid.']").prop("checked", true);

            var category = '.$catid.';
            var poz = '.$poz.';
            $.ajax({
                url:"expense_subcategory_change.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{category:category,
                    poz:poz
                },
                success:function(data){
                    $("#subcategory'.$poz.'").html(data);
                }
            });

            $("input[type=radio][name=kategoria'.$poz.']").change(function(){

                var category = $(this).val();
                var poz = '.$poz.';
                $.ajax({
                    url:"expense_subcategory_change.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{category:category,
                        poz:poz
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#subcategory'.$poz.'").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });


        });
    });

    $("#subcategory'.$poz.'").ajaxComplete(function() {
         $("#subcategory'.$poz.' ").find("option").each( function() {
              var $this = $(this);
              if ($this.val() == '.$subcatid.') {
                 $this.prop("selected","selected");
                 return false;
              }
         });
    });
</script>
```

I've also tried this:

```
    $("#subcategory'.$poz.'").ajaxComplete(function() {
          $("#subcategory'.$poz.' option[value='.$subcatid.']").prop("selected","selected");
    });
```

also these two functions without ajaxComplete for #subcategory or with second ajaxComplete for document

Input with options is loading but first option is always selected.

This is main part of my expense_subcategory_change code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"$sql_query");

$output .= '<select class="mb-3 w-50-100 " name="subcategory'.$poz.'">';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" >'.$row['sub'].'</option>';  
}

$output .= '</select>';

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your selector. You are using 'name' in the select element but using '#' (id) to search the dom for the element. Change your PHP code to:

```
$output .= '<select class="mb-3 w-50-100 " id="subcategory'.$poz.'">';
```

And I tested with the second method you provided as it seemed cleaner

```
$("#subcategory'.$poz.' option[value='.$subcatid.']").prop("selected","selected");
```

See the solution (simplified code) working here https://jsfiddle.net/79kugn60/

Comment: Happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any event. Try Bind that event in your function. So that everytime event gets binded. After firing.